In terser-webpack-plugin, how to keep the string specified in the function？
terser-webpack-plugin version: 5.3.3
webpack version: 5.89.0
enter image description here
function shouldResponse() {
   "worklet";
   return this.responseResult;
}

When I build above code, how to keep the "worklet" string?
enter image description here
